# uniqueliy identify Beacon on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a little problem because I have to uniquely identify beacons on android and iOS. Currently I am using the mac Adress in android. I found out that many beacons (but not all) also show the mac adress in the advertisement data kCBAdvDataServiceData. So i checked the peripheral in iOS like this

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
     let macAdress = advertisementData["kCBAdvDataServiceData"].debugDescription
     print(macAdress)
}
```

this works for 27 out of 33 Beacons but not all. I also can't work with the UUID of the beacons because this value is not equal from iPhone to iPhone. Do you have any tips on how to identify a beacon in Android and iOS?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Set Beacon Major and Minor Value. Both Combination Gives you uniquely identify of Beacon.And you can also change Major and Minor Value of Beacon. Hope this is Helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Apple blocks access to reading the raw mac address of bluetooth devices, so that approach is a non-starter.   And as you have seen, the UUID that Apple assigns to bluetooth devices is not the same across devices, and even changes for a single device at various times.  This same restriction is not present on Android and other platforms.

If you want to uniquely identify beacons with the information from the advertisement packet, **you will need to parse out the beacon-specific identifiers from the advertising data and use this**  (e.g. Eddystone-UID beacon packets contain a 20 byte unique identifier in the advertising data).